TemplateDoesNotExist using django_tables2
I'm developing a Python Django application and I've come across this error: when the view passes a table, I get a "TemplateDoesNotExist" error, but when passing a query, the template works. I've installed 'django_tables2' and added everything to the installed_apps in the settings.py file.
The file log_allarmi.html extends componenti/list.html, which in turn extends base.html.
Installed Apps - settings.py
Template DIR - settings.py
View log_allarmi
Templates tree
I have verified that everything was installed correctly, but I might have overlooked something.
Thank you for the help.
EDIT
I've fixed it. I made some mistakes:

I didn't create the environment correctly.
I didn't create the apps through the terminal; instead, I copied and pasted the folders (I don't think it's very important, but it's better to use the terminal).


Write the code as text instead of image.

Please include code, not images of code: see Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question. [edit] the question and include code fragments with the code sample button ({}).

You should be very careful when copying apps instead of creating them by terminal. You'll have to change some configuration files like apps.py.

Look my answer. Use different names for context variables.

Don't use same context variable name for multiple items.
If you use like below.

"table" :aaa, 
"table" :bbb, 
"table" :ccc, 

Variable "table" value get overwritten and only last ccc get available in template.
You can use like below to avoid this.

"table1" :aaa, 
"table2" :bbb, 
"table3" :ccc, 

